# Sherlock Actionbar suddenly stopped working

Tags: android

My application as been working perfectly fine. Not until when I build some minutes ago and I noticed that all MenuItems in my SherlockAction Bar are not working again. Unfortunately there is no error in the code of such. I don't even know how to trace this. 
I tried deleting and recreating my avd instance. But it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I when into the android properties and remove the sherlock library. I later readded the sherlock library. For some strange reasons the library was not properly read.